# How to assign a default fallback value to a variable

Tags: go

I have a `struct` of pointers in my app

```golang
type body struct {
   A *string
   B *string
}
```

I want to pass the values of `A` and `B` in the `body` to function, such that if the pointer `A` is null, pass a default empty string value. Something like:

```
sampleFunc(ctx,*A||"");

func sampleFunc(ctx Context,count string){
// ......
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a function with your desired logic for computing a value from the pointer. I use generics here so function works with any type.

```
// Value returns the value the value pointed
// to by p or the empty value when p is nil.
func Value[T any](p *T) T {
    var result T
    if p != nil {
        result = *p
    }
    return result
}
```

Use like this:

```
sampleFunc(ctx, Value(A))
```

APIs with `*string` fields often provide a helper function for this purpose.  For example, the AWS API provides the [StringValue](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.44.262/aws#StringValue) function:

```
sampleFunc(ctx, aws.StringValue(A))
```

Comment: There's no reason to complicate this answer with generics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in syntactic sugar for that, just write the code:

```
count := ""
if myBody.A != nil {
    count = *myBody.A
}

sampleFunc(ctx, count)
```

If you find yourself writing this block of code often (say: for many separate fields), you can for example create a helper function:

```
func getOrDefault(val *string, deflt string) string  {
    if val == nil {
        return deflt
    }
    return *val
}


count := getOrDefault(myBody.A, "")
sampleFunc(ctx, count)
```